# Is Roach enchanted?

Tags: the-witcher

If I understand the timeline correctly, Geralt’s horse Roach must have also lived for several (horse) lifetimes.

Is Roach enchanted or magical, or does Geralt simply replace him with a horse of the same name and coloration?

Comment: From the games, I think it's just that every horse he owns is named Roach

Comment: Apparently it wasn't an immortality enchantment

Comment: @HorusKol That is also how it’s explained in the books.

Comment: Yes, the question title isn't particularly well posed.

Comment: Geralt names all his horses Roach out of tradition. According to the Witcher Wiki, "Roach" does not refer to cockroach, but to the fish Common Roach. So this is another "brilliant" translation of these books. There's an episode in one of the books where Geralt needs a new horse and comments about it being a bit skittish for a roach or some such, I can't bother to track down the quote or I'd post an answer. Also, every Roach he has in the books (and games) is a mare.

Comment: @Amarth I don't know what else the translators could've done other than pick a different fish. In the german translation they went with Plötze which is of course quite close to the original Płotka, but I don't think there's anything like that in english.

Comment: @Cubic Maybe they could have picked a random flower, like... Dandelion? :)

Answer (score 30):

It’s not the same horse. Geralt does indeed name each horse he owns “Roach”. At least in the books he didn’t have a particular fondness or dislike for certain horse breeds or colouration, so the horses he owned didn’t all look the same, but if the horse always looks the same in the TV show chances are that’s a production convenience rather than an intentional statement about Geralt or Roach.

That said, the Netflix show *has* deviated from both the books and the games in several points already, some of which pertain to magic and how it works, so it’s not *completely* unthinkable they just decided to make Geralt's horse magic, but it’s unlikely.

---

Also, perhaps worth noting: It's Roach as in the fish, not as in the bug.

Comment: “It's Roach? Roach was a bay, this one is chestnut.”
“All of my horses are named Roach. You know that very well.” 
— from The Sword of Destiny

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot - shouldn't that be an answer? It seems quite authoritative.